# wait until completion block not finished in AFJSONRPCClient request

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am new in IOS and i need your help.
Here is my code.

```
AFJSONRPCClient *client = [AFJSONRPCClient clientWithEndpointURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[client invokeMethod:@"call" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err){
        NSLog(@"errr  %@",[err description]);
    }];
```

i want wait until the response not getting.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Can't you just update the UI/whatever when you get a response and do nothing during the operation?

Comment: @Droppy :: thx for replying...my problem is...above code is define in class A method and and i have a button in class B now when i click on this button method is called from class A and after getting the response from class A method then navigate to the next screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a delegate. Call it when you get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use completion handler block like this:

```
    - (void)doProcess_With_Comp:(void (^)(void))completion{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Add Your process here
        AFJSONRPCClient *client = [AFJSONRPCClient clientWithEndpointURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [client invokeMethod:@"call" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err){
        NSLog(@"errr  %@",[err description]);
    }];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          if (completion) {
            completion();
          }});
      });
    }
```

To call this:

```
[self doProcess_With_Comp:^{
  NSLog(@"Process Completed");}];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: :: i tried your code but i want something different...please see above editable code and let me know how can solve? help me

Comment: @BandishDave when This process completes you need to execute push code on other page right ?

Comment: @cyberlobe :: can i return the value from (NSString *)doProcess_With_Comp() and then check with if condition like returnvalue = [self doProcess_With_Comp:^{
  NSLog(@"Process Completed");}]; if ([returnvalue lenth] == 0){}else{}  ???

Comment: @BandishDave yes for it replace void with Bool & in failure block return false & In success block return true.
than you can check like :  if([self doProcess_With_Comp:^{ NSLog(@"Process Completed");}] == true) something like that.

Comment: @cyberlobe :: when i try to write return statement in failure or success block, xcode gives an error sir..

Comment: than use simply flag variable & try